# Magento orders made by PayPal but not shown in My orders

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am using Magento ver. 1.7.0.2.

My problem is that when any customer put an order on the website then I received payment through PayPal but the order isn't showing up in Magento backend (Orders section)?  I am configuring Paypal Website Payments Standard.

Comment: is it happening for orders placed using payment method other than Paypal ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue as you. It looks like we both need to enable IPN in paypal.

http://shakyaabiral.wordpress.com/2011/08/30/magento-orders-made-by-paypal-not-shown-in-my-orders/

Comment: Links can be helpful as supplemental information, but [link-only answers are frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/228805). Please include a summary of the linked information that's relevant to the question, and explain how it resolves the issue.